# How to set crop box to full width and full height of the container preview(Cropper js)

Tags: javascript

How to make cropper js cropBox equal to container size.
In other words the cropbox area should be equal to the available area of the preview height and width.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution a while ago, and I just realized that I had not answered this question.

The way I managed to set the full width was:

```
var image = document.getElementById('image');
var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
  crop: function(e) {
    console.log(e.detail.width);
    console.log(e.detail.height);

  }
});

var contData = cropper.getContainerData(); //Get container data
cropper.setCropBoxData({ height: contData.height, width: contData.width  }) //set data
```

Comment: you must put var contData = cropper.getContainerDa... in crop event

Comment: @Hüseyin Dursun's answer is the easiest!

Answer (score 15):

A better solution maybe setting  autoCropArea as 1

```
{ autoCropArea: 1}
```

Comment: PERFECT! I spent an hour looking for this answer. Thanks!

Comment: This is now just autoCrop: false - it will hide the crop borders and let you work with the entire image

Comment: @Hüseyin Dursum where do you set this?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov please check https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/blob/main/README.md You will need to put this in the options.